# Which ghastproof block is easiest to obtain renewably in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a humongous base in the Nether. Because of its size, it would be impractical to go for resources to normal world over and over, and I don't want to build portals everywhere, so I'm searching for alternatives. The resource I'm looking for must be immune to ghast fireball explosions (blast resistance of minimum 16.5 as the wiki says) and possible to obtain renewably in large quantities in the Nether.

- For example, a block of emerald would do, because even though you need a villager from the normal world, you can trade with him for emeralds in the Nether once you teleport him there.
- The block must be renewable *in the Nether*, so for example cobblestone is ruled out because it requires water and lava to be made, and water cannot be placed in the Nether.
- The easier the block is obtainable in large quantities *only from renewable methods*, the better.
- The version I'm asking this question for is 1.14.4, so ignore the planned nether update when it comes to answers.

Which of the blocks of Minecraft would best fulfill those criteria?

Comment: I don't think there's a renewable block in the nether if you don't count stuff like Coal Blocks (you can get Coal from Wither Skeleton item drops) which is _very_ inefficient. I think you'd be better off with just going back and forth to the overworld.

Comment: Well, I farm zombie pigmen _in thousands_ for gold blocks, so I have to disagree with you.

Comment: @DarklingArcher I doubt that comes close to the rate someone can mine cobblestone, even if they have to go to and from the nether every thousand blocks or so.

Comment: @Studoku Yes I know, but the point of my question is to find something to build out of without needing to go through the portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately I've recently put together a list of blocks that you can reasonably build a Nether tunnel out of for the description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Gi3nyMlGiU). The ones that can be obtained in the Nether are:

- black and red Nether bricks and their double slabs (not renewable, but Netherrack is extremely abundant and you'll likely dig out tons of it anyway)
- smooth and regular quartz (not renewable)
- purpur blocks and double purpur slabs (requires importing chorus fruit once)
- coal blocks from wither skeletons (slow)
- gold blocks (reasonably fast if you have a gold farm and makes your build awesome)
- emerald blocks from trading for various items (slow)
- obsidian (extremely slow if you don't want to leave the Nether, because it requires you to find it in fortress chests)
- iron blocks and iron bars (insanely slow, because you need to get zombie pigmen to spawn reinforcement zombies and then get iron drops from those)

**So your best renewable option is a chorus fruit farm, but you can also use Netherrack to make Nether bricks if you don't need it for anything else and don't mind "wasting" an unrenewable resource. If you have a gold farm, you can also brag with a golden building.**

Comment: Original question was about blast proofing wrt ghasts...  Are any of these ghast proof?

Comment: Yes, all of them. Otherwise it would be a bad material for Nether tunnels. And except for iron bars (which are only listed because they are a common material for Nether tunnels) they are all solid blocks, meaning skeletons from fortresses can't shoot through, nothing can wash them away and so on. I checked many criteria.